# Is it possible to declare an array using a variable?

Tags: c, arrays, codeblocks

Hi I was told during my first class about arrays in C that you cannot declare them using a variable, for example: `int array[n]`. Yet if I write a code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int array[n];
}
```

Codeblocks doesn't give me any warning or error. How do I know that what I wrote isn't correct?

Comment: VLA's are not allowed by c std. If you aren't getting any compilation error means,compiler has extension. please use dynamic allocation.

Comment: @TruthSeeker VLA has been allowed since C99.

Comment: @TruthSeeker perhaps you intended *"VLA's are not allowed by the C++ std"*?

Comment: [C11 Standard - 6.7.6.2 Array declarators(p4)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.2p4)

Comment: @Barmar: yes  you are right, [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html#Variable-Length).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: thanks for pointing it. I confused between c and c++ std

Comment: Happens to us all, no worries...

Answer (score 1):

This is valid (since C99), although optional (since C11). More portable:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  size_t n = 0;
  int *array = NULL;
  if ((scanf("%zu", &n) <= 0) ||
      (n > SIZE_MAX / sizeof(*array)) ||
      ((array = malloc(n * sizeof(*array))) == NULL)) 
  {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  // Use array

  free(array);  // Don't forget to free the memory.
}
```

Comment: `//Don't forget to error-check or correctly calculate the memory size ;-)`

Comment: I will do that since my professors isn't aware of this update. Thank you

Comment: @PietroAlessandrini Maybe you should inform the professor that their information is out of date.

Comment: `malloc(n*sizeof(int))` and `n` should be `<= SIZE_MAX/sizeof(int)`  so there's no overflow in the multiplication (or do `calloc(sizeof(int),n)` and let `calloc` do the overflow check for you).

Comment: @PSkocik yes. Thank you for the fix. Silly me forgot how `malloc` works...

Comment: @PSkocik "seem incapable of optimizing" --> Try `n == -1`.  I'd expect that to cause `n > SIZE_MAX / sizeof(*array)` to be true.  Its the _signed_ aspect that prevents optimization.  Pedantically a `n < 0` test is needed.  Better to simply use `size_t n`.

Comment: @chux Stupid me. Of course. Thanks! https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Vomeo4

Comment: @PSkocik there's some argument over whether calloc needs to do an overflow check or not  (and some major implementations don't, or didn't)

Comment: @M.M It needs to return a pointer to a zeroed array of `nmemb*size` or `NULL` (http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html). If I do `calloc(SIZE_MAX,SIZE_MAX)` and it gives me a pointer to one zeroed byte (`SIZE_MAX*SIZE_MAX==1`) rather than `NULL`, it has failed the spec, so the logical conclusion is that an overflow check _is_ implicitly required.

Comment: @PSkocik In a way, an overflow check is not needed as a multiple is not required. Code could return a pointer to `SIZE_MAX` objects, each of size `SIZE_MAX` without multiplying.  True that flat memory models imply a needed multiplication, but that is not intrinsic to the function, just the memory model.  IAC, agree that if the pointer returned non-`NULL`, the allocation is expected to have succeeded, even if `n*sz > SIZE_MAX`.

Answer (score 0):

Codeblocks doesn't give you an error or a warning, because there is none. You can do the declaration with no problem since C99.

Comment: Thank you, I guess my professors didn't know about this

Comment: Unfortunately instructors often teach the same syllabus they have for decades.

Comment: VLA have been made optional in C11.